# Mac OS X 10.5 show suffix default

Tags: macos, mac, file-extension

Does anybody know how you can make files show their suffix on default in finder. Currently I have to open the info window for each file and deselect "Hide extension".

Greetings
elhombre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry did search with the wrong term (suffix) I should have looked for extension. So here the answer:

Go in Finder to
Finder/preference/Advanced/Show all file extensions